# Can't use paperclip with Amazon s3 on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm having big time here trying to configure PaperClip to work with Amazon S3 on development environment.

I created an regular resources routes

```
#routes.rb
resources :images
```

On my Image model class I have:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product

has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
  thumb: '100x100>',
  square: '200x200#',
  medium: '300x300>'
}

validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
end
```

my schema.rb is the following:

```
create_table "images", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "views"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "avatar_file_name"
  t.string   "avatar_content_type"
  t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
  t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  t.integer  "product_id"
end
```

my development.rb file has the content:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: 'myownec',
    access_key_id: 'xxxx',
    secret_access_key: 'xxxxx'
  }
}
```

When I create a new image on the resources path and put an binding.pry after the create method:

```
def create
   @image = Image.create image_params
   binding.pry
end
```

then I run:

```
 @image.avatar.url
 => "http://s3.amazonaws.com/myownec/images/avatars//original/Solid_Light_Purple_-_Black_Texture_Background_1920_Hd_Pictures_4_HD_Wallpapers.jpg?1424617420"
```

and if I do:

```
u = Image.last.avatar.url
Image Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images"   ORDER BY "images"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "/avatars/original/missing.png?1424616072"
```

What am I doing wrong?

=(

Comment: try passing a size, `Image.last.avatar.url(:medium)`

Comment: it gives the same error:
"/avatars/medium/missing.png?1424616072"